# Convert getClass from as3 to html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, html5-canvas, animate-cc

I'm trying to convert my as3 project to html5 canvas using animate cc I have the as3 code below to clone MovieClip on stage and need it using html5 canvas.

```
function getClass(obj:Object):Class {
    return Class(getDefinitionByName(getQualifiedClassName(obj)));
 }
var mc=getClass(this.getChildByName("myMc"))
```

Comment: _"..using animate cc"_ So what's the exact problem? Does Animate CC refuse to  generate or export HTML content from the AS3 code? Do you get error message(s)?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: Class is not defined

Comment: Are you converting this to JS? If so, may we see the JS?

Comment: the code inside html5 canvas var stage=this
function getClass(obj) {
    return Class(getDefinitionByName(getQualifiedClassName(lib.obj)));
 }var mc=getClass(stage.nn.getChildByName("Mymc"))

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by creating a `function getClass`? Maybe there's a different solution... Anyways, I doubt you can `return Class` also there are no function parameters allowed for a `Class` object so no point for the code with `...getQualifiedClassName(obj)...` etc. The [**AS3 Manual**](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Class.html) tells you on its line 8 that _**"Generally, you do not need to declare or create variables of type Class manually."**_ and your `return Class` logic sounds like trying to manually create a Class, is that right?

Comment: if I want to create new instance from a movieClip in the library by giving it a linkage name we can do like this "var mc=new lib.myMc" where myMc is the linkage name but my problem is that I want the linkage name in arabic language :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's it :)

```
stage.nn.gotoAndStop("cow");
var mc=stage.nn.getChildAt(0).clone()
mc.x=100
mc.y=100
stage.addChild(mc)
```

Thanx All :)